web3 and etherscan api getTransactionCount for nonce returning 0
const propagateAddress = "0xd6616Cf7F133F0c00E2712718B8133c20E3F6605"
const web3 = new Web3("https://rpc2.sepolia.org");
var nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(propagateAddress)
console.log(nonce)
//0n


//same problem
axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: 'https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionCount&address=' + propagateAddress + 
          '&tag=latest&apikey=' + apiKey,
        })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data.result)
                        //0x0

          });


So nonce is turning 0 for propagateAddress. But server expects nonce 83 and I have 86 transactions on etherscan https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x68663eb789cb1b20eba9f693fdf927dc195db114
If I enter the nonce manually the transaction goes thru. Most of my transactions are on a custom coin contract. Could this be a problem with the Sepolia test network?
